# Ionic app with Agora-Rtc-SDK - stream play issue

Tags: ionic-framework, webrtc, progressive-web-apps, agora.io

i'm trying a little esperiment using agora-rtc-sdk inside a ionic app PWA.
Actually i'm using ver 3.5.2 sdk (ver 4 is not available over npm).

All seems ok (streams starts, join etc) bunt i'm having problems with play() function.
Play function take a DOM id to build a local player to show a stream, but using inside angular it does not work. Is there another way to take the stream an append it to video element?

Thanks
Flavio

Comment: provide some source code, of what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Agora Web 3.x SDK, it's very much possible to take the stream and manually create the video element yourself.

Use the `stream-subscribed` callback to create a new `<video/>` object and connect the stream as the source. You'll have to add an event listener for `onloadmetadata` before you can call `play()`.

```js
// connect remote streams
client.on('stream-subscribed', (evt) => {
  const remoteStream = evt.stream;
  const remoteId = remoteStream.getId();
  console.log('Successfully subscribed to remote stream: ' + remoteId);
  
  // create video element
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.id = 'agoraVideo-' + remoteId;
  video.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', 'webkit-playsinline');
  video.setAttribute('playsinline', 'playsinline');
  console.log(video);

  video.srcObject = remoteStream.stream;// add video stream to video element as source
  video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
    // ready to play video
    video.play();
  }
  // Add video element to the DOM
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
localStream.init(()=>{
    // Play the local stream
    localStream.setVideoProfile('720p_5');
    const playerContainer = document.createElement("div");
    playerContainer.id = uid;
    playerContainer.style.width = "40%";
    playerContainer.style.height = "40%";
    playerContainer.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    playerContainer.style.position = "fixed";
    document.body.append(playerContainer);
    // let c =  document.body.append(playerContainer)
    localStream.play(`${playerContainer.id}`, { fit: "contain", muted: false }, function (errState) {

    });
    // Publish the local stream
    this.client.publish(localStream);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).